# OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished is not fired with LoginBehaviorApplicationOnly Facebook.Client LoginButton

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I've created Windows Phone application (WinRT for 8.1+, not the Silverlight one). I've added the Facebook 6.0.10.0 and Facebook.Client 0.9.1.0 with Nuget manager (not the Github build) and I have added "FacebookConfig.xml" to the project with content as described in http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/config/, fb[Facebook-app-id] to the Package.appxmanifest as Protocol in Declarations and override of OnActivated in App.xaml.cs.

```
    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnActivated(args);
        Session.OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished += OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished;
        var protocolArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        LifecycleHelper.FacebookAuthenticationReceived(protocolArgs);
```

with event handler

```
private void OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished(AccessTokenData session)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished");
    }
```

On the main page I created LoginButton:

```
<controls:LoginButton x:Name="FacebookLoginButton"
                                      Height="70"
                                      Margin="5"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      FetchUserInfo="True"
                                      LoginBehavior="LoginBehaviorApplicationOnly"
                                      Opacity="0"
                                      Permissions="email, public_profile"
                                      SessionStateChanged="LoginButton_OnSessionStateChanged"
                                      Visibility="Visible" />
```

With event hendler of SessionStateChanged

```
   private void LoginButton_OnSessionStateChanged(object sender, SessionStateChangedEventArgs e)
   {
           Debug.WriteLine(e.SessionState);    
   }
```

The button example in documentation seems to be outdated as ApplicationId is no longer field of LoginButton and I've found confirmation to that on stackoverflow but the logic should work nonetheless and it does. I works great and exactly as expected with                                     LoginBehavior="LoginBehaviorWebViewOnly". But when LoginBehavior is set to the LoginBehaviorApplicationOnly what happens is that event SessionStateChanged is fired once before opening facebook with state "Opening", Facebook application opens allowing you to enter credentials, displays loading screen, closes and goes back to my Application login button screen. What is strange that there is no "permissions confirmation dialogue" of any sort and after going back to my application no events are fired. Neither SessionStateChanged of LoginButton nor OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished from App.xaml.cs.

The debug Output gives error:

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ApplicationId' property not found on 'Facebook.Client.Controls.LoginButton'. BindingExpression: Path='ApplicationId' DataItem='Facebook.Client.Controls.LoginButton'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' (Name='PART_LoginButton');   target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
```

Please pardon my strange grammar and all mistakes as English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

"ApplicationId" is no longer valid parameter as I know. Check http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/config/ for more details. You have to add facebookconfig.xml and configure manifest.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you wanted to help but you didn't even bother to read anything, right? It's WinRT (.NET core) app not Silverlight so http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/config/ applies and I carefully described how I followed instructions to the letter.